# C# web image gallery

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-gallery

Can anyone point me in a direction to create a photo gallery using only C# code for a website? I know there is javascript but I'd like to know how to do one in C#. Does C# even have any of the capabilities required to do a gallery like javascript does?

Bellow are examples of javascript galleries. Is it possible to do this in just plain old C#?

[autoviewer](http://www.simpleviewer.net/autoviewer/app/)

[postcardviewer](http://www.simpleviewer.net/postcardviewer/app/)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **yes** (and **no** at the same time)!

**Yes** - it is possible to create a site using C# (IIS web server and [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/)).

**No** - it is not possible to avoid using JavaScript/Flash/Silverlight/etc. if you want to make your side *dynamic and fancy*.

The web still needs **HTML** to show a page, so you would use C# to create HTML code and the browser will render it and display it.

If you are happy with just a list of images (no fancy sliders or accordeon controls, or whatever that is moving) = **static content** - then look at [ASP.NET / MVC4](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

If you want to create a fancy site using C# and avoid writing the JavaScript for yourself then add a framework like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) or [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) on top of ASP.NET / MVC - the frameworks will handle the fancy stuff for you.

Comment: Thank you for a nice an easy answer. I don't want static non fancy stuff. But if you can't achieve it without using javascript then fair enough. I just wanted to know if it was possible